# When importing SQL file to the database using command line, wrong MySQL user is used

Tags: mysql, shell, command-line, debian

I have MySQL user `company_dev` who has access to DB `company_dev`, and user `company_prod` who has access to DB `company_prod`.

When I'm logged as a root on my Debian server, I try to import SQL file to my `company_dev` DB.

This is the command I'm using: `mysql -u company_dev -pMyPassword company_dev < some_db.sql`

But I get this error:

> Access denied for user 'company_dev'@'localhost' to database
>   'company_prod'

If I correctly understand this message - there was an attempt to write a file `some_db.sql` to  the `company_prod` DB, even though I put `company_dev` in the command?!

How is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: logged in as root on the server is not analogous to the root user of the mysql server, they are different.

Please check the following:

- Check the password is right, also might need to put it in quotes: 
  -p'passWordHere'
- **The file some_db.sql** probably has some statement to **insert into** someDbName. Check it.
- the user you are importing with is 
  -u **company_dev**
  you need to make sure this user has permissions.

To grant permissions, use this sql, you will need something like this:

```
 GRANT [type of permission] ON company_prod TO ‘company_dev’@'localhost’;
```

This all depends on the permissions you need to give the user, 
all privileges would be something like this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'company_dev'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'll take a look at the link you provided.

But, I'm not sure if I was totally clear.
User `company_dev` has all permissions on `company_dev` DB.

But when I execute the command from my question, it seems that user `company_dev` is trying to import SQL file into `company_prod` DB.
Even though in the command clearly stays that SQL file must be imported to the `company_dev` DB by the user `company_dev`!

Comment: I think the second item you wrote is the problem - "The file some_db.sql probably has some statement to insert into someDbName. Check it."

There is SQL

`CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ company_prod/*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 */;

USE company_prod;`

Comment: I'll need to find a way to export only data from `company_prod`, without these command for creating DB.
So I can import that data in the `company_dev`.